# Problema al restablecer password Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy desarrollando un sistema multitenant donde tengo un dominio principal,

> midominio.test

y un dominio para cada cliente,

> cliente1.midominio.test, cliente2.midominio.test, cliente3.midominio.test

Cuando registro un usuario desde uno de los subdominios, recibo el mail con el correspondiente enlace para verificar la cuenta:

> cliente1.midominio.test/email/verify...

y lo puedo validar sin problemas.

El problema aparece cuando quiero restablecer el password de ese usuario registrado desde el subdominio, el correo que se envía, contiene la url de actualización pero apunta al dominio principal, no al subdominio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví agregando un middleware que detecta la URL del tenant y la setea en la variable *url* del archivo de configuración *config/app.php*.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $tenant = $this->subdomain();

    $urlTenant =  'http://' . $tenant . '.jmovilmt.test';
    config(['app.url' => $urlTenant]);

    return $next($request);
}

public function subdomain()
{
    $host = explode('.', request()->getHost());
    $tenant = $host[0];
    return $tenant;
}
```